# I want to create store procedure of selecting record of last 3 months from 3 tables

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE data.select_data_last_three_month()
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare
v_time1 timestamp;
Begin

    select to_timestamp(to_char(current_date-94,'yyyy-mm-dd'),'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') into v_time1;

    select q1.*,q2.*,q3.* from
    (select * from public.table1 where time >'v_time1' order by time desc) q1, --'2020-05-25 00:00:00'
    (select * from public.table2 >'v_time1' order by time desc)q2,
    (select * from public.table3 time >'v_time1' order by time desc) q3
    ;

 END;
$procedure$
;

call data.delete_interface_tcp_data_three_month_back()
```

If I call this procedure it gives this error:

> SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "v_time1"

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your code:

1. don't convert timestamps back and forth between strings, dates and timestamps. A simple assignment is enough.
2. references to variables shouldn't be enclosed in single quotes. `'v_time'` is a string, `v_time1` is a reference to the variable.
3. procedures are not intended to return results, you need to use a function declared as `returns table (...)`

Putting all that together, your function should look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE function data.select_data_last_three_month()
  returns table (... your column definitions go here ....)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$procedure$
declare
  v_time1 timestamp;
Begin

    v_time := current_date - 94;

    select q1.*,q2.*,q3.* 
    from  
    (select * from public.table1 where time > v_time1 order by time desc) q1, --'2020-05-25 00:00:00'
    (select * from public.table2 > v_time1 order by time desc)q2,
    (select * from public.table3 time > v_time1 order by time desc) q3
    ;

 END;
$procedure$
;
```

You don't actually need PL/pgSQL for this. A `language sql` function would be enough.

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from data.delete_interface_tcp_data_three_month_back();
```

But I **highly** doubt, a *cross join* (cartesian product) between the three tables is what you want. If the three tables have the same structure, then you probably want a `UNION ALL`.